# Informing a custom delegate class in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have successfully set up a delegate in my `NSObject` class and I'm able to transfer some data and run some selectors.

The thing is, I can't understand how do I send some values back to that class where I've set up my delegate. I have a ViewController, `SGDownloader` that has a `BOOL` property and I want to check it on the delegate class to make a conditional firing of some selector. The thing is, I can't seem to make it work. I'm using storyboards and here's my code:

```
-(void)checkTheQueue {
    SGDownloader *downloaderInstance = [SGDownloader new];
    NSLog((@"Downloader is now %i"), downloaderInstance.isBusy);
    BOOL checkBool = downloaderInstance.isBusy;

    if (checkBool == NO) {
        SEL selector = @selector(checkTheThing);
        if (delegate && [delegate respondsToSelector:selector]) {
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
            [delegate performSelector:selector];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
        }
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Sorry, I'm busy");
    }
}
```

I fire the selector `checkTheThing` in my first class, the class I'd like to get the `isBusy` value from. It's also an `@optional` delegate method.
The thing is, that the `BOOL` value is always 0, and if I try to pass a string it's always `nil`.

I suspect there's a problem with this line - `SGDownloader *downloaderInstance = [SGDownloader new];` maybe the storyboard get's mixed up or something like that.

**Edit:**

Part of the code from `SGDownloader`:

```
- (IBAction)attemptNewDownload:(id)sender {

    SGQueueController *myProtocol = [SGQueueController new];
    myProtocol.delegate = self;
    NSLog((@"Busy value equals %i while checking the protocol"), isBusy);
    [myProtocol checkTheQueue];
}
```

Here `NSLog` tells me that the value is 1. Seconds later it's 0 on my protocol class. Although nothing is done with it later on.

Comment: Where do you set the busy flag? If you create a new downloaderInstance every time you call ceckTheQueue it will return the same value for isBusy.

Comment: "the class I'd like to get the `BOOL` value from" "if I try to pass a string it's always `nil`" What is the signature of the method you're trying to call? How do you pass a string, and where are you expecting to get a `BOOL` result? (Also, it's considered bad form to call `new` instead of `alloc/init`. It obscures the default initializer in case it isn't `init`.)

Comment: @rsswtmr I'm setting `isBusy` to `YES` in `ViewDidLoad` and I just want to pass this value to the delegate. I've tried substituting value with a string but the result was the same so I deleted that part of the code. I'm evaluating the `BOOL` result right in the `checkTheQueue` method as you can see and this method is fired AFTER I set my `BOOL` value. No matter what I use (`alloc/init` or `new`) the result is the same.

Comment: So how does `SGDownloader` work? Re: what Johan said, if you create one at the head of the method, there's no chance for your `viewDidLoad` code to set the busy flag before you check it.

Comment: @rsswtmr check out the edit to the post

Comment: There is ***nothing*** special about a delegate.  Forget it's a delegate and just consider it to be normal code.  Debug in the normal way.

Comment: @HotLicks I think I understand but the question still remains then, how do you inform it of the changes in the first class? Debug is no use when you don't know how to do this or that.

Comment: To "inform" a class instance you must somehow have a "trail" to it -- a series of pointers, starting where you are, and ending up at the target object.  Then you must have "pass-through" methods (or simply access to read the intermediate pointers) so you can get to the target object.  Figure out your pointer sequence and you have your answer.  If there is no pointer sequence you must create one somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Code should work, but you're looking at the wrong Place.

`isBusy` gets set in `viewDidLoad` of SGDownloader, right? In `attemptNewDownload` you create an Instance of SGQueueController. Then you set its Delegate to the already created SGDownloader and call `checkTheQueue` on it.

In `checkTheQueue` you create a new Instance of SGDownloader, but `new` doesn't call `viewDidLoad` (by default). So the `isBusy`-property of the newly created SGDownloader-Instance is still NO. Just let out the `[SGDownloader new]`-line and change

`BOOL checkBool = downloaderInstance.isBusy;`

to

`BOOL checkBool = delegate.isBusy;`